# ASP.NET: MVC 4 - Simple Login with Web Services as the data store

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an **ASP.NET MVC 4** application with **Forms** Authentication.

In my Account controller I receive the username and password from the form.

A **web service** returns a true/false if the username/password are correct.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
         bool isValid=MyWebService.ValidateLogin(model.Name,model.Pass);

          if(isValid){
            *** Here: Tell ASP.NET that model.Name is a logged in user
            ***       and to keep a cookie so that they stay logged in ???
            RedirectToAction(...);
           }
     }
```

I hope to leverage as much of the ASP.NET infrastructure as I can, but to use the Web Service to get the login right.

Comment: Are you after something like Single Sign On (OpenId, OAuth, SAML), implementations include DotNetAuth or WIF.

Comment: No, I just want ASP.NET to be told that the current user is logged in and can enter the site and each subsequent  page is allowed. Really simple.

Comment: You're probably going to have to create a custom login model here's a couple of links to give you some ideas: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/custom-login-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/05/04/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive way to do this with framework-level support is to implement a custom `MembershipProvider`.  It's pretty straightforward, and there are very easy-to-implement features.  If you want to leverage the other pieces of membership, authentication and authorization, this is likely your best route.  Here are your steps:

- Create a new class called `YourMembershipProvider`
- Inherit from `MembershipProvider` and implement the abstract methods
- Look through the methods and implement the ones that count, namely:

  - `ValidateUser`
  - `GetUser`

Your `GetUser` will take the `username` and use your web service to look up any relevant member details that you want to track.

`ValidateUser` will be where you call your web service.  Return `true` if the user checks out.

Finally, update your web config.  In System.Web, you'll need something like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="YourMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="YourMembershipProvider" type="YourNamespace.YourMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

So, to recap...implement your class, wire up your web config, use the framework to handle the rest.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, maybe i woud add another parameter in your call to the webservice to return an errorvalue if there is an error in logging in.

```
bool isValid=MyWebService.ValidateLogin(model.Name,model.Pass, rtnErrorStatusCode);
```

Once your webservice has logged the user in you can always check if the user is logged in with

```
If (Request.IsAuthenticated = False) Then
  ' This user has not logged in
  ' redirect to login page here
End if
```

As for the cookie, I guess its only necessary if you want to persist some session information.

And saving a cookie will just give you a different method of knowing the user is logged in, but the "Request.Authenticated" statement also tells you if the user is logged in or not as it returns a boolean value, so maybe having the cookie just duplicates that, so unless your storing session specific info (like the user prefs or theme etc) maybe the cookie is not needed.